# Adding suffix to duplicate file in Apple Script

Tags: applescript, automator

I am attempting to write a script to allow me to keep my Downloads folder clean, this is great for uni/work as files get moved to their correct folders to allow linking in apps etc.

I have a script working for if a file does not exist, it will move the file to the selected folder (prompts user for folder) and I have added an option to delete the new file if it exists if the user wants, however I want to add an option to keep both files, with the new file being renamed with a "_2" added on the end of the name for the second "_3" for the third and so on.

As far as I have it, I am prompting for a manual name change, along with that not working, I can see it adding inefficiency. This is as far as I have it:

```
(* Version 1.2b
Move to Bin prompt added
Fixed activate Finder
add ability to keep a duplicate *)

on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileToMove to item 1 of input
        set fileName to name of fileToMove
        set fileExtension to name extension of fileToMove ¬
            --gets extension incase file needs to be renamed
        activate
        set chosenFolder to POSIX file choose folder with prompt "Select a folder to move " & fileName & " "
        log chosenFolder
        
        try
            move fileToMove to folder chosenFolder
            -- Make sound play only on success
        on error
            -- Display notification with title "File Not Moved" subtitle "File with that name already exists at that location"
            
            display alert "Duplicate File Found" message "Would you like to move " & fileToMove & " to the Bin or Keep & Rename?" buttons {"Move Duplicate to Bin", "Keep & Rename", "Cancel"} default button "Keep Both" cancel button "Cancel"
            set buttonReturned to button returned of result
            
            if buttonReturned is "Keep Both" then
                display dialog "Set New File Name for: " & fileName & "  " default answer fileName with icon note
                set newName to result
                set the name of fileToMove to newName
                set the extension of fileToMove to fileExtension
                move fileToMove to folder chosenFolder
                do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/Volume Mount.aif'"
            end if
            
            if buttonReturned is "Move Duplicate to Bin" then
                -- Move the file to the trash
                move fileToMove to trash
            end if
        end try
    end tell
end run
```

Any other suggestions, refinements welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't work anyway because the button names don't match and a single quote character is missing in the `do shell script` line.

Never mind, you need a handler which checks the file name and adds an index.
This is a bit cumbersome because the case *no extension* must be covered and if there is an extension you have to strip the extension from the file name.

`POSIX file choose folder` is not needed.
`choose folder` is sufficient and you can delete the `folder` keywords.

The only way to move and rename a file simultaneously is with `mv` of the shell.

```
(* Version 1.2b
Move to Bin prompt added
Fixed activate Finder
add ability to keep a duplicate *)

on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileToMove to item 1 of input
        set fileName to name of fileToMove
        set fileExtension to name extension of fileToMove ¬
            --gets extension incase file needs to be renamed
        activate
        set chosenFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select a folder to move " & fileName & " "
        log POSIX path of chosenFolder
        
        try
            move fileToMove to chosenFolder
            -- Make sound play only on success
        on error
            -- Display notification with title "File Not Moved" subtitle "File with that name already exists at that location"
            
            display alert "Duplicate File Found" message "Would you like to move " & fileToMove & " to the Bin or Keep & Rename?" buttons {"Move Duplicate to Bin", "Keep & Rename", "Cancel"} default button "Keep & Rename"
            set buttonReturned to button returned of result
            
            if buttonReturned is "Keep & Rename" then
                set newPath to my checkFileName(chosenFolder as text, fileName, fileExtension)
                do shell script "mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of fileToMove & space & quoted form of POSIX path of newPath
                do shell script "afplay '/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/Volume Mount.aif'"
            end if
            
            if buttonReturned is "Move Duplicate to Bin" then
                -- Move the file to the trash
                move fileToMove to trash
            end if
        end try
    end tell
end run

-- fDir: HFS path destination folder
-- fName: full file name
-- fExt: name extension

on checkFileName(fDir, fName, fExt)
    if fExt is "" then
        set fullExt to fExt
        set baseName to fName
    else
        set fullExt to "." & fExt
        set endIndex to offset of fullExt in fName
        set baseName to text 1 thru (endIndex - 1) of fName
    end if
    set _index to 0
    repeat
        set _index to _index + 1
        set newPath to (fDir & baseName & "_" & (_index as text) & fullExt)
        try
            newPath as alias
            -- file exists – repeat again
        on error
            -- file does does not exist – return new path
            return newPath
            
        end try
    end repeat
end checkFileName
```

Comment: Thank you for help! This is exactly how I want it to work! legend!

Comment: I've been using the script for a bit now, and have found that if there is duplicate file it will work correctly (ie filename_1, however if there is another duplicate, it will name the second duplicate incorrectly ie filename_1_1, how could this be corrected?